# What type of SQL query do I need to use when my column data type is SET?

Tags: mysql, sql, set, where-clause

**MYSQL TABLE** my_contacts

```
contact_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name VARCHAR(255),
interests SET('Animals','Trading Cards','Geocaching','Horseback Riding','Movies','Hiking');
```

**SQL QUERY**

```
SELECT * FROM my_contacts WHERE interests = 'Animals';
```

**Example**

If I have a record in my table with interests **Animals** the query above works fine. ;-)

But if I have a record in my table with interest **Animals**,**Hiking** the query above does not return any result. :-(

Why?

Comment: Use `LIKE 'Animals%'` Btw,you are storing your data wrong.

Comment: LIKE '%Animals%' This will match even if Animal is in between. I agree to @Mihai.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. I am sure you are so right about the code that I use is wrong. I am pretty new in MySQL.  I am trying to learn :-) Question, so for my future reference, when I have multiple choice to assign to a column do I need to still use SET?

Comment: Set is OKish,but you are not using the relational power of the database by storing more than 1 value in a cell.Because now you dont have 2 hobbies but a string which needs elaborate queries to take apart.

Comment: Thank you to every one. I know have a lot to study :-( Have a beautiful week end.

Answer (score 3):

Use  [`FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT * FROM my_contacts WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Animals', interests) > 0;
```

More info about SET type and operations: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html